# Images preview in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I have to preview image and as a response from backend i got weird answer:

```
�PNG
IHDR
�rO�\3=5=]�i:B"�,�N�g簂��}����x���朻��k}
�{���ϓ�����O�������Խ��"^���0�W�����ıH���)^�\�����/����I"I���wS}�WD�%�ǵ<���~.�|
```

and so on. It has more and more questions. I put this result in $scope.image and i tried with
`<img ng-src="{{image}}" />` but nothing happens.

Comment: It's not clear what you think it odd about that as a response - basically it's binary data, the PNG image. If you're treating it as text, that could well be problematic.

Comment: well looks like you are getting an image and src expects a url, sounds like you should just be sticking the url your backend calls as the src.

Comment: Need to convert it to a Data URL or have server return url instead of file content

Comment: thanks guys for answers....but is there any way i can preview image from this response ?

Comment: what is the response type? I am guessing Applicaiton/octect right?

Comment: Write your API calling link with image id (however you are calling it) directly in src tag. It worked for me. E.g. <img ng-src="http://somelink.com/api/getImage/{{imageID}}" />